# Can i change the default Mac App Store install folder?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I prefer to have all applications installed per-user, to `~/Applications/` rather than globally. The default location for apps installed from the Mac App Store is the global applications folder located at `/Applications/`.

Is there a `defaults write com.apple.AppStore` command I can run in the terminal, or perhaps a `.plist` file I can edit manually, to change this default preference?

Comment: Knowing why you do **not** prefer `/Applications` might generate some more creative answers …

Comment: I offered the bounty because on our shared Mac at home I want the apps I download to only be available for my User. I want to install the apps in ~/Applications.

Comment: I also want apps bought with my Apple ID only available to my user. Others who have accounts on a shared computer will fill /Applications with their apps and I'll fill it with mine, it's a pain to deal with one huge pile of apps. I like the separation.

Comment: Plus this would/should/could allow people to use the App Store without System Administrator permissions: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6065/do-i-need-to-have-system-administrator-permissions-to-install-from-the-mac-app-st

Comment: I am searching for solutions to install large apps such as games to an SD card I have permanently inserted to my MacBook since the internal SSD is only 120GB; sadly I attempted to 'upgrade' the SSD with an NVMe replacement but it failed with kernel panics, so I have no choice but to do this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding *Mac OS X File System Overview*, it seems Apple enforcing the standard compliance for developer to follow their rules on application folder which are within /Applications or ~/Applications. The concern is to comply the way Mac App Store deliver the updates.

if you not comfort enough to use default folder, yes you are still able to move the application which you had download from Mac App Store to another folder with two caveats:

1. You will be required to enter an administrative password to move the
   app from the /Applications folder.
2. If an update appears in the MAS for an installed app that has been moved you will get an error message about having apps installed
       from another account. To update the app you will have to Delete
   the
       app entirely and then install the updated app or Move the app back to the /Applications folder

Comment: I was hoping there was a solution for this but you've provided the best explanation and the annoyances of executing this customization. +50

Answer (score 2):

At this point there is no details on this (But I am sure there is a property or .plist) but in the meantime you can create a simple Automator "Folder Actions" workflow, that moves the apps to the folder of your choice. This is simple and mostly happens in the background.

One problem I see with this is how Updates work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option, while it is not exactly what you asked for, it will accomplish most of your goals:

1. Create a new folder at the root of your boot drive and name it
   PubApplications, duplicate the permissions of the Applications
   Folder.
2. Copy (Option Drag) **Don't Move** all applications that you
   want publicly accessible to that folder.
3. Copy **Don't Move** the apps you want in your ~/Applications folder to that folder.
4. Rename /Applications to /Applications.bak or /.Applications.bak if you want
   it hidden.
5. Create a symlink in your root folder named Applications, pointing to the Applications folder in your home directory.

   `ln -s /Users/your_name/Applications /Applications`

I am not sure who uses the computer besides you, and I am also not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, whether it is to streamline backups, or keep your apps private from others, or if this is simply where you like to install apps.

Note - the above above method will break things for other users if they exist. You could use:

```
ln -s ~/Applications /Applications
```

instead of the previous symlink command, although I have had issues with that and you would need to ensure each user had a ~/Applications folder.

Answer (score 0):

I usually move all my applications acquired from the MAS in a subfolder, e.g. `Applications/Games` or `Applications/Utilities` or whatever suits better.
As *wongacid* said, you will be required an administrative password to perform the move.
I have already had several updates to my apps, so it seems updating moved applications works flawlessly, at least for programs kept within the `Applications` folder. I can not be sure about other locations, though.